# Как правильно запустить Python (micro)сервис для работы с NATS?

Tags: python, события, архитектура, микросервисы

Что у меня есть сейчас:

- Сервис записи в БД (валидирует входящие данные, ищет
  дубликаты)[`FastAPI`]
- Сервис конвертации и преобразования данных
  (забирает данные из сервиса БД и создаёт `Celery` таски)[`FastAPI`]
- Сервис с `Celery` на борту + к нему `Redis` в качестве брокера
- Сервис фронта (не я пилил, хз что там), который взаимодействует с первыми
  двумя апишками [`NestJS`]
- Собственно сам фронт [`Angular`]

Соответственно, как пример:
После записи данных в базу я из сервиса БД дёргаю эндпоинты сервиса конвертации, что бы инициировать конвертацию в форматы по умолчанию. Если нужен другой формат, то пользователь жмёт нужные кнопки из интерфейса, а сервис фронта уже дёргает ручки сервиса конвертации. Всё это надо логировать, в будущем понадобится сквозная трассировка и т.п. При обрастании функционалом (и следовательно, увеличении кол-ва сервисов) увеличится взаимодействие, повысится связность. Придётся обрабатывать в коде случаи отваливания части сервисов и т.п. Как я понимаю, если перейти с ручного дёрганья эндпоинтов на событийную модель взаимодействия сервисов, можно будет привести систему к следующему виду:

- Сервис записи в БД
- Сервис ручной инициации конвертации, преобразования - апишка без логики создания задач, просто эндпоинты, создающие эвенты по типу - была запрошена конвертация в такой-то формат.
- Сервис конвертации
- Сервис преобразования данных
- Сервис фронта
- Фронт

Тогда, имея `Pub/Sub` шину в виде `NATS`, я могу всё сделать следующим образом. Пользователь отправляет данные в сервис БД, после валидации данные пишутся в БД и в `NATS subject` пушится сообщение (эвент) с информацией о новых данных. На этот эвент у нас подписаны сервисы конвертации и сервис фронта. Соответственно, в сервисе конвертации должна начаться конвертация, а у пользователя на страничке мигнуть лампочка - данные записаны, всё ок.
Сервис конвертации, при начале конвертации создаёт эвент - началось. На этот эвент подписан фронт - пользователю мигает соответствующая лампочка и дальше в том же духе. С первого взгляда всё просто, но вот при дальнейшем обдумывании у меня возникают вопросы.
При создании `REST` сервисов я использую `FastAPI`, для него существует настроенный `Docker` образ, в котором достаточно положить приложение в определенное место и всё заверте... Упакованные в такие образы апишки способны обслуживать огромное количество пользователей. Однако, из того, что я описал выше видно, что не все сервисы - `REST API`. Сервисы конвертации и преобразования данных - по факту просто скрипты вынесенные в отдельные контейнеры и я не имею понятия, как грамотно это всё организовать. Если я напишу скрипт, который просто в бесконечном цикле ожидает сообщения (эвенты) в `subject`'е `NATS`, то как правильно потом это всё запускать в контейнере, что бы скрипт мог обслуживать сразу n-ное количество эвентов. Нужно ли это вообще? Есть ли примеры, статьи, видео по теме? Всё что нахожу - очередные "Как запустить `Flask` в докере!"

Как одно из предположений:
В сервисах конвертации и преобразования создавать всё те же `Celery` таски и держать параллельно сервис с его воркерами, в которых так же пушить в `NATS` эвенты с инфой о ходе процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы можно было одновременно обрабатывать несколько сообщений из очереди `NATS` достаточно запустить несколько процессов, которые слушают определенную очередь и находятся в одной [группе](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/queue):

`NATS` посылает каждое сообщение одному слушателю из группы. Собственно слушатель и будет бесконечно в цикле ждать сообщения из `NATS`.

Теперь о вариантах как одновременно запускать нескольких слушателей:

1. несколько контейнеров
2. несколько процессов в контейнере
3. python-nats (c asyncio под капотом)

### Несколько контейнеров

Конкретный способ зависит от того, что используется для оркестрации. Если docker swarm, то задайте для сервиса количество слушателей с помощью параметра `--replicas`. Если используете k8s, то используйте ключ `spec.replicas` в определении `Deployment`. Если запускаете вручную, то просто делаете `docker run ...` необходимое количество раз.

Еще одна возможность - использовать docker-compose.

### Несколько процессов внутри контейнера

Можно сделать и так хоть и не рекомендуется, так как подход имеет очевидные минусы:

1. усложняется устройство самого контейнера (т.к. нужно процессы запускать, за ними следить, перезапускать при сбое и т.д.)
2. при сбое контейнера или хоста на котором он запущен вся обработка останавливается

Смотрите на [способы](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) запуска нескольких процессов.

### python-nats (c asyncio под капотом)

Тут точно не подскажу, т.к не использовал, а документация скудная. Точно будет один слушатель и в лучшем случае будет некий естественный параллелизм, степень которого будет определяться тем, какую долю времени задачи конвертации будут проводить в ожидании ввода-вывода. Т.е. когда выполнение обработчика сообщения от `NATS` блокируется на вводе-выводе, то `python-nats` может (теоретически, это то то чего я точно не знаю, по-этому я говорю о "лучшем случае") взять новое сообщение и его обрабатывать. Тут нужно протестировать поведение `python-nats` (или [задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)).

Comment: То есть, если я хочу использовать `nats-python`, использующий `asyncio`, то мне надо не запускать несколько процессов в одном образе подключенных к одной очереди, а реплицировать контейнеры с одним процессом на борту? Если про оркестрацию пока не идёт речь, то всё-таки можно запустить в  одном контейнере в нескольких процессах?

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев добавил немного